# SQLite compare query from 2 tables

Tags: sqlite

I would like to create a new query for know how many product are in the store.

table: **tb_store**

```
    +--------+------------+------------------+-----------+
    | item_id| nome       |  data_out        |   data_in |
    +--------+------------+------------------+-----------+
    | 1      | Produ1     | null             | 2015-01-06|
    | 2      | Produ1     | null             | 2015-01-06|
    | 3      | Produ3     | null             | 2015-01-06|
    | 4      | Produ3     | null             | 2015-01-06|
    | 5      | Produ5     | null             | 2015-01-06|
    | 6      | Produ4     | 2015-01-06       | 2015-02-06|
    | 7      | Produ2     | 2015-01-06       | 2015-02-06|
    +--------+------------+------------------+-----------+
```

table: **tb_product**

```
+--------+------------+
| item_id| nome       |
+--------+------------+
| 1      | Produ1     |
| 2      | Produ2     |
| 3      | Produ3     |
| 4      | Produ4     |
| 5      | Produ5     |
+--------+------------+
```

i have write this query:

```
select nome, count(nome) as pezzi from  tb_store where data_out is null or data_out="" group by nome order by pezzi desc
```

the result are:

```
+--------+------------+
| nome   | pezzi      |
+--------+------------+
| Produ1 | 2          |
| Produ3 | 2          |
| Produ5 | 1          |
+--------+------------+
```

i would like to obtain this result:

```
+--------+------------+
| nome   | pezzi      |
+--------+------------+
| Produ1 | 2          |
| Produ3 | 2          |
| Produ5 | 1          |
| Produ2 | 0          |
| Produ4 | 0          |
+--------+------------+
```

is possible? how can rewrite the query?

**EDIT**

I have create a new query like this:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT nome, pezzi FROM(
SELECT nome,COALESCE(pezzi,0)as pezzi FROM(
SELECT p.nome, COUNT(s.nome) as pezzi
FROM tb_product as p LEFT JOIN tb_store as s
ON   p.nome = s.nome
WHERE s.data_out is null
OR    s.data_out = ""
GROUP BY p.nome
union
select nome,null as pezzi from tb_product) )
ORDER BY pezzi DESC
```

but i have some duplicate item to remove....the result is

```
nome         pezzi
crema         2
pistacchio    2
zabajone      2
bacio         1
cassata       1
cioccolato    1
ciocco rum    1
malaga        1
mango         1
mascarpone    1
nocciola      1
stracciatella 1
bacio         0
caramello     0
cassata       0
cioccolato    0
ciocco rum    0
crema         0
fragola       0
limone        0
malaga        0
mango         0
mascarpone    0
nocciola      0
pistacchio    0
zabajone      0
```

is possible to remove the duplicate that are 0?

```
SELECT DISTINCT nome, pezzi FROM(
SELECT nome,COALESCE(pezzi,0)as pezzi FROM(
SELECT p.nome, COUNT(s.nome) as pezzi
FROM tb_product as p LEFT JOIN tb_store as s
ON   p.nome = s.nome
WHERE s.data_out is null
OR    s.data_out = ""
GROUP BY p.nome
union
select nome,null as pezzi from tb_product) GROUP BY nome ) 
ORDER BY pezzi DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do a left join between the two tables like:

```
SELECT p.nome, COUNT(s.nome) as pezzi
FROM tb_product as p LEFT JOIN tb_store as s
ON   p.name = s.name
WHERE data_out is null
OR    data_out = ""
GROUP BY p.nome
ORDER BY pezzi DESC
```

Comment: i have tried on DB Browser for Sqlite to simulate the query and the result are:
no such column: date_out: SELECT p.nome, COUNT(s.nome) as pezzi
FROM tb_product p LEFT JOIN tb_store s
ON   p.name = s.name
WHERE date_out is null
OR    date_out = ""
GROUP BY p.nome
ORDER BY pezzi DESC

Comment: Above in your post you showed us you have date_out field and now you are getting error? Can you please check exact name?

Comment: ok the query run, but appear only data > 0, not show the data = 0
I have posted the file (mycpstore.db) for example:
http://www.filedropper.com/mycpstore

Comment: update the table, but i think that the problem is the where condition, probably i need to create an apped od data in two different query

Comment: Yes because where says either data is null or empty. So what are you looking now?

Comment: the first your query is perfect, the second query I think to be :
WHERE p.nome are not present in the first query.  The result of the second query have to be appended to the result of the first query. I hope to be clear.....

Comment: i have update the query, is possible to remove the duplicate?